# SharePoint 2010 Migration to SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, modern-experience, 2019, sitepages

My company is migrating to SharePoint 2019 (on-premise) from SharePoint 2010.  We migrated the content over, but when I click a link in the top navigation, some pages go to the classic view, while others are in a modern view.  Also, when I click the main department page, it takes me to a "page not found" page, in classic view.

Is it possible to migrate the old site so that all pages are in the Modern view?  I'm trying to avoid building all new pages in the modern site.

Answer (score 0):

Classic SharePoint sites typically have classic pages being wiki pages, web part pages, blog pages or publishing pages and these pages cannot present themselves using a modern user interface.

So, you may need to transform classic pages to modern pages either manually or using coding like PowerShell.

Check below Microsoft official documentations for same:

1. [Transform classic pages to modern pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages)
2. [Transforming to modern site pages using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages-powershell)

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Did Ganesh Sanap's answer helps you?